# How to check if a field has been populated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I made a calculator with Google Maps which shows fixed prices between departure and destination.

But The price show only after leave the input and click on the map or on the div.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

  function initMap() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.379189, 4.899431);
    var mapOptions = {
      center: latlng,
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      styles: [{"featureType":"water","stylers":[{"saturation":43},{"lightness":-11},{"hue":"#0088ff"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"hue":"#ff0000"},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":99}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#808080"},{"lightness":54}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ece2d9"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ccdca1"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#767676"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"poi","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.natural","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#b8cb93"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi.sports_complex","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi.medical","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"poi.business","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]}]
        };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
  }

  function drivingRoute(from, to) {
    var request = {
      origin: from,
      destination: to,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
    };
    if(typeof(drivingLine) !== 'undefined') drivingLine.setMap(null);
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status){
      if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){

        var totalKM = Math.round(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);
        var distanceText = totalKM+' km';
        $('#controls p').text(distanceText);

        var stadsdeelTest = document.getElementById('stadsdeel').value;
        if (stadsdeelTest=='Centrum') {
                    var charges=  '€ '+ 32;
            }
        else if (stadsdeelTest=='Amsterdam-Oost') {
                    var charges=  '€ '+ 35;
            }
        else if (stadsdeelTest=='Oud-Zuid') {
                    var charges=  '€ '+ 30;
            }

        $('#controls h2').text(charges);

        drivingLine = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: response.routes[0].overview_path,
          strokeColor: "#b00",
          strokeOpacity: .75,
          strokeWeight: 5
        });
        drivingLine.setMap(map);
        map.fitBounds(response.routes[0].bounds);

      }

      else {
        $('#controls p').addClass('error');
      }

    });

  }

  $('input').blur(function(){
    drivingRoute(
      $('input[name=from]').val(),
      $('input[name=to]').val()
    );
  });

  $(function(){
        $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
          details: "form",
          types: ["address"],
          country: 'nl'
        });

        $('input').blur(function(){
          $("#geocomplete").trigger("geocode");
        });
      });


  var map;
  var drivingLine;
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  initMap();
  $('input[name=to]').val('Schiphol');
  $('input[name=from]').trigger('blur');
});

// Autocomplete
      var fromText = document.getElementById('geocomplete');
      var cityBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(52.379189, 4.899431));
      var options = {
          bounds: cityBounds,             
          types: ['geocode'],
          componentRestrictions: {country: 'nl'}
      };

  // google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
  //    window.alert("you selected an item from suggestion list");
  //  });

  $( "input" ).change(function() {
  document.getElementById("bestemming").focus();
            return false;
});

document.getElementById('geocomplete').onkeypress = function (e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            document.getElementById("bestemming").focus();
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rMEdKO/

Try to put "Damrak, Amsterdam, Nederland" on the departure field and click on the map. It show the price for the sublocality Centrum.

And after change the destination to "Ceintuurbaan, Amsterdam, Nederland" it doesn't change the price, only after clicking on the map.

I want to show the price right after fill in the destination, and if the user change the destination. The price must change automatic.

Comment: I tried both those places, and then clicked on the autocomplete dropdown item, it worked. Both the map and price updated automatically. I did not have to click on the map to make it change. Are you saying you want to update it without the user selecting the place from the dropdown ?

Comment: @Searching can you try without selecting from the suggestion/dropdown? It doesn't update the price if you don't select from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using get `blur` event try the `change` event on your `input`

```
  //This is what you have
   $('input').blur(function(){
    drivingRoute(
       $('input[name=from]').val(),
       $('input[name=to]').val()
    );
  });


   //Remove/modify the code above and try this
    $('#geocomplete').bind('input', function() { 
        drivingRoute(
          $('input[name=from]').val(),
          $('input[name=to]').val()
        );
    });
```

Not completely sure if this answers you question/issue.

Comment: no it doesn't work, first it shows the else price after clicking on the map it show the correct price for the correct sublocality...